# What Pokemon is this?

Tags: pokemon, pokemon-detective-pikachu

I haven't really played the later generations of Pokemon, but I still recognized 99% of all Pokemon shown in Detective Pikachu - except one:
[image]

Which one is this?

Comment: Is it wrong to downvote this question for not being phrased "Who's that Pokemon?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Ludicolo from the Hoenn region

[image: Ludicolo GIF]

CGI Ludicolo has the characteristic lily pad on its head and orange lips (beak?).

Don't worry, you're not the only one creeped out by the CGI's look.

[image]